# How to delegate calling parameter ($self) to other method

Tags: perl, mojo, mojolicious

I am learning mojolicious::lite.

In router, delegate the parameter to controller, use this code ok:

```
get '/hello/:name' => sub {
  my $self = shift;
  ControllerTest::hello($self);
  };
```

Should there any short hand method, eg:

```
get '/hello/:name' => ControllerTest::hello( shift ); #this code not work
```

thanks.

Comment: Your intent isn't clear. In high-level terms, what are you trying to do?

Comment: Feels like you should be using Mojolicious and not Mojolicious::Lite

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm not a mojolicious hacker :)

That won't work since 'shift' pulls data from the current context (from @_). I would guess the shortest (short hand) would be:

```
get '/hello/:name' => sub { ControllerTest::hello( shift ); };
```

or maybe by using a sub reference:

```
get '/hello/:name' => \&ControllerTest::hello
```

Then the first argument passed into `hello` would be all the args passed to the anonymous sub used. I haven't tried this but I suspect it will work :)

Comment: I haven't tried it either, but this should work and is probably the shortest way.

Comment: There's also the semi-mysterious (if you haven't read perlsub): `get '/hello/:name' => sub { &ControllerTest::hello; };`  And if you want to get really weird: `get '/hello/:name' => sub { goto \&ControllerTest::hello; };`

Comment: All methods in this answer works, include coment by daotoad. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to call it as a method directly by using the fully qualified name, e.g.

```
get '/hello/:name' => sub { $self->ControllerTest::hello(); };
```

Comment: Can't call method "param" on an undefined value at lib/ControllerTest.pm line 6. The parameter not pass to the hello() method.